# Graphics card for a coding desktop with three displays

Tags: desktop, video, multiple-monitors

I am looking for a graphics card that would be used in a desktop pc running GNU/Linux used mainly for coding. I won't run any games that would require high performance, but I want the card to support three 1920x1080 monitors via digital ports. Nice to have: ability to run OpenCL/CUDA on this card. So what is the cheapest way to meet these requirements?

Comment: Modern integrated graphics should meet all your requirements. As to which GPUs are good... your other requirements would be important, as right now, the answer is pretty much all of them.

Comment: What else do you want from the graphics card? Should it be as small as possible? As power-efficient / power-saving as possible? As cheap as possible? As silent as possible?

Comment: @Alpha3031: are you saying that all currently manufactured Intel HD GPUs have support for 3 displays and OpenCL?

Comment: @SEJPM As cheap as possible.

Comment: I would try looking at Newegg.com, and other hardware sellers on your own first, before coming here and having people do the same for you.

Comment: I would agree with this, except the user is asking for a card with 3 display ports. It's a low effort question, but I think it falls within the guidelines (barely). Wonder what a mod would say.

Comment: All Intel graphics released after Sandy Bridge supports OpenCL 1.2 on Linux. Partial 3 monitor support was also introduced in Ivy Bridge, and Haswell and later fully supports it, provided you have a motherboard with connectors matching your monitors. Since there isn't really much restricting GPU selection, I suggest combining it with a CPU selection question. This would help narrow the scope of the question, and if you get an iGP, the price depends on the CPU it's attached to.

Comment: @Alpha3031 Are there many motherboards with 3 display ports?

Comment: They're pretty easy to find. Most of them have mixed connectors and at least one VGA output though,  so you'd either have to rely on adaptors or use DisplayPort daisy chaining.

Answer (score 1):

This [GTX960](http://pcpartpicker.com/product/TLkwrH/zotac-video-card-zt9030110m) seems to meet your needs. 3 display ports, and with this one or any [OpenCL](https://compubench.com/device.jsp?benchmark=compu20&testgroup=info&os=Windows&api=cl&D=NVIDIA%20GeForce%20GTX%20960) API, it meets your other criteria. Under $200 also meets your "As cheap as possible" criteria.

Now, like others have said, most newer cards are going to meet your criteria, and using PCpartpicker you can select cards that have 3 display ports. So if my suggestion doesn't fit your bill, you should be able to find what you're looking for fairly quick.